# Is the tight binding model an effective free fermion model?

Tags: hamiltonian, fermions, tight-binding

The tight-binding Hamiltionian has the form

$$H=-t\sum_i\left(c_i^\dagger c_{i+1} + c_{i}c_{i+1}^\dagger\right)$$

But does this mean that it can be represented in the form of free fermion modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a free fermion model on a **Lattice** with translational symmetry. It is different from a free fermion gas.

You need to clarify your question regarding 'can be diagonalized'. Surely, given enough computer resources/speed, you can diagonalize any Hamiltonian. In the case of a free fermion model, you can use the single particle states (as the basis) to create the Hamiltonian and diagonalize it numerically.

OR

You can solve the problem analytically using the discrete (on a lattice) Fourier transform to go from real-space (as written in your question) to the momentum space. This 'transform' will rotate the Hamiltonian into a diagonal basis, hence, you diagonalized the Hamiltonian where the  `momentum' states are the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.